# texturing in OpenGl

Tags: opengl

Am new to openGl,and i have a couple of things using it.
so what am trying to do  is to draw a cube ,but apply a texture to only one surface of it...i couldn't find the answer on some random sites i found on google,they all talk about texturing a whole 3D object,so is it possible to only apply it to one surface or not?!

thank u!

Comment: Are you using the fixed function pipeline or the programmable pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Nehe's OpenGL tutorials are the #1 resource I would recommend to start OpenGL development. At least, this is where I started from ;-)

Here is the link: http:// nehe.gamedev.net

Texturing is addressed in [Lesson 6: Texture Mapping](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=06)

Comment: This article discuss texturing the whole object, not just a part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

`glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`

before rendering the one surface, and then right before the other surfaces:

`glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`

You have to of course make sure you're loading your texture, setting it up, and binding it before getting to the point of rendering your surfaces.

Comment: This is obviously the right answer for the fixed-function pipeline. However, for the programmable pipeline glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) has no effect.

Comment: Given the OP's "Am new to openGl", I *hoping* he's starting out with fixed-function. :)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I agree with you on that. Fixed-function can be quite a detour these days. I think I'd recommend beginners to learn about shaders before texturing, as texturing is where fixed function programming starts to become a horrible mess ;)

Comment: Yeah, hard to say, but I come from the perspective of using OpenGL since 1.0 (1993!), so for me, I would always advise someone to start out with fixed-function if they are new to graphics programming (and, as many programmers oddly seem to be, afraid of math).. otherwise, they would get drowned pretty quickly. :)

Answer (score 0):

You must also add texture coordinates to the vertices of the polygons that you want to apply a texture to. To do this you must use glTexCoord2f/glTexCoord2d. So, for example, if you have the following (untextured) polygon:

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glEnd();
```

Add texture coordinates like this:

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glEnd();
```